# Como definir resolução da foto ou como alterar para oculpara o ImageView inteiro

Tags: android

estou usando a função da camera do android preciso alterar a resolução da imagem para ocupar meu ImageView por completo

codigo utilizado

```
public void onClickCamera(View v){

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(photo);       
}
```

alguma dica ou um modo melhor para utilizar e obter o resuldado esperado ou como o instagram faz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for apenas para visualmente diminuir a imagem, pode-se alterar a propriedade ScaleType do ImageView para `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE`, de modo que o ImageView irá redimensionar a imagem proporcionalmente quando for desenha-la:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

Contudo, essa solução acaba consumindo um pouco mais de processamento, pois a imagem é redimensionada toda vez que a imagem precisar ser desenhada.

Se isso for um problema, é possível utilizar um pouco mais de memória, e criar uma cópia menor do bitmap, já com o tamanho do ImageView (por padrão essa operação deve ser realizada em outra Thread / Task):

```
Bitmap reduzido = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, LARGURA_DESEJADA, ALTURA_DESEJADA, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(reduzido);
```

Isso vai economizar processamento, já que o ImageView não precisará redimensionar a imagem toda vez, mas gasta um pouco mais de memória.

Comment: como eu faria para utilizar o imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); poderia dar um exemplo se possível?

Comment: Editei a resposta com o exemplo a partir do seu código original.

Comment: obrigado deu para resolver meu problema